# Pandas rolling `on` parameter as level of MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I am trying to use the [pandas rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function with a series whose index is a MultiIndex.  I am trying to set the `on` parameter to one of the index levels but I get an error, even though the documentation explicitly says an Index level is a valid argument ("For a DataFrame, a column label or **Index level** on which to calculate the rolling window, rather than the DataFrame’s index.")  Below is an example showcasing the error.

---

Initializing toy data:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1,2,3,4], pd.date_range(start="1-1-2023", end="1-4-2023")], names=["number", "time"])
ser = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3,4], index=idx)
print(ser)
```

Produces:

```
number  time
1       2023-01-01    1
2       2023-01-02    2
3       2023-01-03    3
4       2023-01-04    4
dtype: int64
```

When I try to do rolling setting the parameter `on="time"`, attempting to access the "time" level of the MultiIndex, I get an error:

```
out = ser.rolling("2D", on="time").mean()  # ValueError: invalid on specified as time, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None
```

However, if I bring the "time" level from the index into a DataFrame column, I can perform the rolling with `on="time"` with no error.  But I then need extra boilerplate to bring it back to the index after the computation I do with the rolling object

```
out = ser.reset_index("time").rolling("2D", on="time").mean()
out = out.set_index("time", append=True)
print(out)
```

Gives:

```
number  time      
1       2023-01-01    1.0
2       2023-01-02    1.5
3       2023-01-03    2.5
4       2023-01-04    3.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As [`rolling` as no `level` keyword](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34642), you can use this workaround with `on` parameter:

```
>>> ser.rolling('2D', on=ser.index.levels[1]).mean()

number  time      
1       2023-01-01    1.0
2       2023-01-02    1.5
3       2023-01-03    2.5
4       2023-01-04    3.5
dtype: float64
```

If your `time` index is not ordered, you have to sort it before:

```
>>> ser.sort_index(level='time').rolling('2D', on=ser.index.levels[1]).mean()

number  time      
1       2023-01-01    1.0
2       2023-01-02    1.5
4       2023-01-03    3.0
3       2023-01-04    3.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for pass `Index` to parameter `on`:

```
out = ser.rolling("2D", on=ser.index.get_level_values("time")).mean()
print (out)
number  time      
1       2023-01-01    1.0
2       2023-01-02    1.5
3       2023-01-03    2.5
4       2023-01-04    3.5
dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (ser.index.get_level_values("time"))
DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04'], 
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)
```

Comment: @Corralien - Testing and for me working perfectly. `idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1,2,4,3], pd.date_range(start="1-1-2023", end="1-4-2023")], names=["number", "time"])
ser = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3,4], index=idx)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm wrong for `number`. Can you try `idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1,2,3,4], [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-1'), pd.Timestamp('2023-1-2'), pd.Timestamp('2023-1-4'), pd.Timestamp('2023-1-3')]], names=["number", "time"])
ser = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3,4], index=idx)`?

Comment: (and my answer is not better in this case)

Comment: @Corralien - hmmm, I got `ValueError: DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None) must be monotonic`, but I think why should be DatetimeIndex not sorted?

Comment: I don't know but it could be the case.